# Why is the submit button in my ChildForm tyring to post the main form?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is my view it has 1 Main Form that consists of 3 child form inside.

```
@*MainForm*@
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create_SelectPersons","Appointment", FormMethod.Post))
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Step 2</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
       @*Child Form1*@
        using(Ajax.BeginForm("AddAttendeeManual", "Attendee", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "doneManualEmail" }))
        {
             @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedManualEmail.AppointmentId)
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedManualEmail.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-8 input-group">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedManualEmail.Email, new {@class = "form-control",PlaceHolder="Email"}) 
                   //button below tries to submit entire form(main) and not the child form
                    <input type='submit' class="btn btn-default" value="Add>>" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }


        if (Model.IsSuperOfficeConnected)
        {
            @*Child Form2*@
            using(Ajax.BeginForm("AddAttendeeSuperOffice","Attendee",new AjaxOptions{HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "done"}))
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.FirstName, new { id = "SelectedSuperOfficeEmail_FirstName" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.LastName, new { id = "SelectedSuperOfficeEmail_LastName" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.AppointmentId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.SuperOfficePersonId, new { id = "SelectedSuperOfficeEmail_SuperOfficePersonId" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-8 input-group">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.Email, new { id = "SelectedSuperOfficeEmail", @class = "form-control", PlaceHolder = "Search in SuperOffice" })

                        <input type='submit' id="btnSuperOffice" class="btn btn-default" value="Add>>" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            }

        }
        if (Model.IsInternalAddressBookEmpty)
        {
            @*Child Form3*@
            using(Ajax.BeginForm("AddAttendeeInternalAddressBook", "Attendee", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "done" }))
             {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.FirstName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.LastName)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.AppointmentId)
                 <div class="form-group">
                     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                     <div class="col-md-8 input-group">
                         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.Email, new { id = "SelectedAddressBookPerson", @class = "form-control", PlaceHolder = "Search in AddressBook..." }) 

                         <input type='submit' id="btnAddressBook" class="btn btn-default" value="Add>>">
                     </div>
                 </div>               
             }

        }


       <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
             <input class="btn btn-default" value="<<Previous"/>
              //this button which i am expecting to submit the main form, does nothing
             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Next>>" />
         </div>
    </div>

}


<style>
    .ui-autocomplete-loading {
        background: url('/Content/themes/base/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif') no-repeat right center;
    }

</style>
@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")

    <script type="text/javascript">    
        $(function () {

            $("#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail").
                autocomplete({
                    source: '/Appointment/SuperOfficePerson',
                    minLength: 1,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $('#SelectedSuperOfficeEmail').val(ui.item.value);
                        $(@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.FirstName)).val(ui.item.FirstName);
                        $(@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.LastName)).val(ui.item.LastName);
                        $(@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.SuperOfficePersonId)).val(ui.item.ExternalPersonId);
                    }

            });

            $("#SelectedAddressBookPerson").autocomplete({
                source: '/Appointment/AddressBookPerson',
                minLength: 1,
                select: function(event,ui) {
                    $(@Html.IdFor((m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.FirstName))).val(ui.item.FirstName);
                    $(@Html.IdFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.LastName)).val(ui.item.LastName);
                },
            });

        });
        function doneManualEmail() {
            $(@Html.IdFor(m => m.SelectedManualEmail.Email)).val('');
        }
        function done() {
            $(@Html.IdFor(m=>m.SelectedSuperOfficeEmail.Email)).val('');
            $(@Html.IdFor(m=>m.SelectedAddressBookPerson.Email)).val('');
            $(@Html.IdFor(m=>m.SelectedManualEmail.Email)).val('');
        }

    </script>
}
```

In the above code for the `Child Form1` and `Child Form3`, when I submit click the button next to them it submits the child form, but for the Child Form1 when i click button next to it shouldn't it be submitting the child form?

Right now it is trying to submit the mail form. Why is that?

And the Next button of type submit, for the main form does nothing when i click it.

How should I solve this issue?

Edit 1: According to answer, I could solve this problem by removing the main form and having a jquery on click function for the Next>> button. But then why does second and third child form work and not first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is not valid HTML**. You can use multiple forms but cannot use nested forms.

From official [**W3C XHTML specification prohibitions**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions)

> form must not contain other form elements.

Comment: So the better idea would to remove the main form and have a jquery code for next button which would forward me to post method of the controller? But then why does other two child form work?

Comment: @Biplov13, Yes thats the better idea

Comment: @Biplov13, When HTML is invalid we cannot predict, how it will behave